# Lista de grupos de usuários com ldap

Tags: php

Eu sou muito novo com **LDAP** e eu fiz uma conexão entre o meu servidor php e meu servidor de anúncios. Agora eu quero listar todos os grupos, para que os usuários veja se ele é um administrador ou não (ou pode haver outro caminho?).

Eu tenho esse codigo até agora:

```
$ldap = ldap_connect("192.168.1.108");
    if ($ldap && $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $name."@redward.org", $pw)) {
        // ldap_search e ldap_get_entries aqui eu acho, mas como?
    }
```

Eu tentei com ldap_search lendo o manual no php.net mas eu não poderia fazê-lo funcionar como um todo. Alguém pode me mostrar como fazê-lo funcionar?

Answer (score 2):

Caso queira obter todos os grupos disponíveis no servidor LDAP pode utilizar o filtro "(objectClass=group)", desta forma filtrará todos os registros que possuem o objectClass do tipo "group".

```
$res = ldap_search($ldap, 'dc=redward,dc,=org', '(objectClass=group)');
print_r(ldap_get_entries($link, $res));
```